# Converting Months to Years

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to figure out how to convert months to years in Age.
I've read through some questions but can't seem to find a response yet.

```
library(Stat2Data)
data("Kids198")
glimpse(Kids198)

kidsGraph <- 
  ggplot(data = Kids198,
         aes(
         x = Age,
         y = Height,
         color = as.factor(Sex),
         )) +
  ggtitle("Boys and Girls Height by Age"
         ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("Orchid", "Dark Blue"), 
    name = "Gender", 
    labels = c("Female", "Male")
    ) +
  labs(
    x = "Age (years)",
    y = "Height (inches)"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous() +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()
  

kidsGraph
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You may divide the `Age` value by 12.

```
library(ggplot2)

Kids198$Age <- Kids198$Age/12

ggplot(data = Kids198,
       aes(
         x = Age,
         y = Height,
         color = as.factor(Sex),
       )) +
  ggtitle("Boys and Girls Height by Age"
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("Orchid", "Dark Blue"), 
    name = "Gender", 
    labels = c("Female", "Male")
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "Age (years)",
    y = "Height (inches)"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous() +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()
```

[image]